# Plot from different datasets upon different inputs using conditional statement

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I have recently started working on shiny, for my school project I am developing a Shiny application that plot the graph using ggplot upon selected inputs.

Now, one of my requirement is that, upon selecting certain inputs in the front-end I have to plot the graph using certain dataset. Say I have 3 different datasets, and 4 inputs then,

```
if(input$A = 1 && input$B = 2 && input$C = 3 && input$D = 4){ 
  //Plot using Dataset1
} 
else if(input$A = 1 && input$B = 2 && input$C = 3 && input$D = 4){ 
  //Plot using Dataset2
}
else if(input$A = 2 && input$B = 3 && input$C = 4 && input$D = 4){ 
  //Plot using Dataset3
}
```

I figured out that for this sort of logic to work, I need a submit button in the form, I've checked a couple of examples online, but dint properly understand how to apply it in my case.

Now, when I try to plot the data using if condition using reactive as below, I am getting `Error:could not find function "g"` 
What am I doing wrong here? and how will I be able to plot this information upon Submit button?

I'd appreciate it, if you could please take a look at my code below and help me.

Here's a [sample dataset](https://ufile.io/67y10) you can use to reproduce the example -

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library("RMySQL")
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
# Database Connection and the fetch
dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE)
dataset$X <- NULL
dataset$sex <- sub("^$", "Unknown", dataset$sex)

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .shiny-output-error-validation {
        color: #48ca3b;
        font-size: 14pt;
      }
      body {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9); /* Moz-browsers */
        zoom: 0.9; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
        zoom: 90%; /* Webkit browsers */
      }
    "))
    ),
    titlePanel("Define census"),

    sidebarPanel(

    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date Input',
                   start = as.Date("1967-01-01"), end = Sys.Date()),

    selectInput("region", label = "Region", 
                choices = c("All",levels(dataset$region)), 
                selected = "ANI"),

    selectInput("species", label = "Species", 
                choices = c("All",levels(dataset$species)),
                selected = "ANI"),

    selectInput("sex", label = "Sex", 
                choices = unique(dataset$sex), multiple = TRUE, 
                selected = unique(dataset$sex)),

    radioButtons(
      "standard_cat_options",
      label="Standard Category",
      choices=list(
        "All",
        "Multiple Select"), selected="All"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.standard_cat_options != 'All'",
      selectInput(
        'standard_cat', 
        label = "Select categories", multiple = TRUE, 
        choices=unique(dataset$standard_cat)
      )
    ),

    radioButtons(
      "age_cat_options",
      label="Age Category",
      choices=list(
        "All",
        "Multiple Select"), selected="All"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.age_cat_options != 'All'",
      selectInput(
        'broad_cat',
        label = "Select age category", multiple = TRUE,
        choices=c("adult", "adjuv", "juv", "pup", "orphan", "W", "YOY", "SA1", "SA2", "SA3", "SA4", "SA5", "SA", "mature", levels(dataset$broad_cat))
      )
    ),

    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),

    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[8]]),

    submitButton("Submit")
    ),
  mainPanel(
    column(12, plotlyOutput("plot1")),
    hr(),
    column(12, plotlyOutput("plot2"))
   )
  )
)
```

Updated **Server.R**

```
library(ggplot2)
library("RMySQL")
library("mgcv")
library(plotly)
function(input, output) {

# Database Connection and the fetch
  dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE)

  dataset$X <- NULL
  dataset$sex <- sub("^$", "Unknown", dataset$sex)

  # dataset1 <- read.csv("dataset1.csv", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  # dataset2 <- read.csv("dataset2.csv", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  # dataset3 <- read.csv("dataset3.csv", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

# DataBase disconnected 
# Using the datafram created with name data 
# as in the given data Date is of String type so converted to "Date" type

dataset$date <- as.Date(dataset$date)

#reactive variable initiation for the various inputsinstall.packages('rsconnect')

reactive({
#if(input$region == "ANI" && input$species == "Ej" && input$sex == "Unknown" && input$standard_cat == "All" && input$broad_cat == "YOY"){

if(input$region == "ANI"){
  l <- subset(dataset, region %in% input$region)

  k <- subset(l(), date >= as.Date(input$dateRange[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$dateRange[2]))

  m <- subset(k(), species %in% input$species)

  n <- subset(m(), sex %in% input$sex)

  o <- subset(n(), standard_cat %in% input$standard_cat)

  g <- subset(o(), broad_cat %in% input$broad_cat)
  } 
})

#output plots 

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(g(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point(alpha=0.4)
    ggplotly(p)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    q <- ggplot(g(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_smooth()
    ggplotly(q)
  })
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to wrap all of those reactive expressions inside of another reactive expression. I would remove it. I also don't think you need those reactive expressions in the first place if I understand what you are trying to accomplish here. With each input from the UI you can specify the default input. I would do this rather than validating that each input has a value. This should also remove the need for a submit button.

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for the feedback, I tried removing the reactive expressions as suggested. But I am finding myself looking at same error again.